# Make R shiny plot interactive, such that when clicked on a bar, it redirects to another tab with filtered data

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I have this R shiny plot which is somewhat interactive, when I select some Practice Area it adjusts the graph to the selected areas, as well as the point, line and text.
I want to make it so that if I click a specific bar in the stacked bar plot, it redirects me to another "Filtered" tab, which gives the dataset but according to the filters, ie the specific month and specific practice area I clicked
I tried to use observeEvent and some other javascript in the ui, but nothing worked.

```
output$stackedBarPlot <- renderPlot({
    excess <- excess_supply()
    
    # Filter the data based on the selected Main Practice Areas
    selected_areas <- input$mainPracticeArea
    if (!is.null(selected_areas)) {
      excess_filtered <- filter(excess, `Main Practice Area` %in% selected_areas)
    } else {
      excess_filtered <- excess  # If no areas selected, use all data
    }
    
    
    # Calculate the Overall Excess by summing Excess by Month for the selected practice areas
    overall_excess <- excess_filtered %>%
      group_by(Month) %>%
      summarize(Overall_Excess = sum(Excess, na.rm = TRUE))
    
    # Create a ggplot stacked bar plot with filtered data
    # Customize the plot further based on your data and visualization preferences
    ggplot() +
      geom_bar(data = excess_filtered, aes(x = Month, y = Excess, fill = `Main Practice Area`), stat = "identity") +
      geom_point(data = overall_excess, aes(x = Month, y = Overall_Excess), color = "blue", size = 3, show.legend = FALSE) + 
      geom_text(data = overall_excess, aes(x = Month, y = Overall_Excess, label = Overall_Excess, fill = NULL), nudge_y = 10) +
      geom_line(data = overall_excess, aes(x = Month, y = Overall_Excess, group = 1), color = "darkblue", size = 0.85, show.legend = FALSE) +
      labs(title = "Excess Supply by Main Practice Area",
           x = "Month", y = "Excess Supply") +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(legend.title = element_blank())
    
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends whether the tabs with the filtered data already exist or if you want to create a new tab on clicking a bar.

## First case: tabs already exist

If they already exist (easiest case), here is an example, with artificial data.

```r
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(htmlwidgets) # to use the 'onRender' function

dat <- iris
dat$Season <- gl(2L, 1L, 150L, labels = c("Spring/Summer", "Autumn/Winter"))

# Calculate the average sepal width per season
aveWidth <- dat %>%
  group_by(Season) %>%
  summarize(Average_width = mean(Sepal.Width, na.rm = TRUE))
aveWidth_filtered <- dat %>%
  group_by(Season, Species) %>%
  summarize(Average_width = mean(Sepal.Width, na.rm = TRUE))

# JavaScript code
js <- "
function(el, x) {
  el.on('plotly_click', function(d) {
    var point = d.points[0];
    var season = point.x;
    $('.nav-tabs a[data-value=\"' + season + '\"]').tab('show');
  });
}"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Overall", plotlyOutput("ggly_overall")),
    tabPanel("Spring/Summer", plotlyOutput("ggly_ss")),
    tabPanel("Autumn/Winter", plotlyOutput("ggly_aw"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output[["ggly_overall"]] <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(aveWidth, type = "bar",
            x = ~Season, y = ~Average_width
    ) %>% onRender(js)
  })
  
  output[["ggly_ss"]] <- renderPlotly({
    data <- filter(aveWidth_filtered, Season == "Spring/Summer")
    plot_ly(data, type = "scatter", mode = "markers", 
           x = ~ Species, y = ~ Average_width
    )
  })

  output[["ggly_aw"]] <- renderPlotly({
    data <- filter(aveWidth_filtered, Season == "Autumn/Winter")
    plot_ly(data, type = "scatter", mode = "markers", 
            x = ~ Species, y = ~ Average_width
    )
  })
  
}
```

[image]

## Second case : new tab is created on click - single tab only

Here is an example of creating a new tab on clicking a bar, *with one weakness*: one can create only one new tab; previous tab if any is replaced with new tab. Allowing multiple new tabs is more complicated.

```r
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(htmlwidgets) # to use the 'onRender' function

dat <- iris
dat$Season <- gl(2L, 1L, 150L, labels = c("Spring/Summer", "Autumn/Winter"))

# Calculate the average sepal width per season
aveWidth <- dat %>%
  group_by(Season) %>%
  summarize(Average_width = mean(Sepal.Width, na.rm = TRUE))
aveWidth_filtered <- dat %>%
  group_by(Season, Species) %>%
  summarize(Average_width = mean(Sepal.Width, na.rm = TRUE))

# store all possible seasons
seasons <- unique(dat[["Season"]])

# JavaScript code
js <- "
function(el, x) {
  el.on('plotly_click', function(d) {
    var point = d.points[0];
    var season = point.x;
    Shiny.setInputValue('season', season);
  });
}"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Overall", plotlyOutput("ggly_overall")),
    id = "tabset"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output[["ggly_overall"]] <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(aveWidth, type = "bar",
            x = ~Season, y = ~Average_width
    ) %>% onRender(js)
  })
  
  seasonData <- eventReactive(input[["season"]], {
    filter(aveWidth_filtered, Season == input[["season"]])
  })
  
  output[["ggly_season"]] <- renderPlotly({
    data <- seasonData()
    plot_ly(data, type = "scatter", mode = "markers", 
           x = ~ Species, y = ~ Average_width
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input[["season"]], {
    # remove existing tab if any
    for(tab in setdiff(seasons, input[["season"]])) {
      removeTab("tabset", tab)
    }
    # append the new tab
    appendTab(
      "tabset",
      tab = tabPanel(
        title = input[["season"]],
        plotlyOutput("ggly_season")
      ),
      select = TRUE
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

## Third case: new tab is created on click - multiple tabs

Here is the same as before but allowing multiple new tabs. The problem to deal with is the fact that one cannot use two different HTML elements with the same id.

```r
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(htmlwidgets) # to use the 'onRender' function

dat <- iris
dat$Season <- gl(2L, 1L, 150L, labels = c("Spring/Summer", "Autumn/Winter"))

# Calculate the average sepal width per season
aveWidth <- dat %>%
  group_by(Season) %>%
  summarize(Average_width = mean(Sepal.Width, na.rm = TRUE))
aveWidth_filtered <- dat %>%
  group_by(Season, Species) %>%
  summarize(Average_width = mean(Sepal.Width, na.rm = TRUE))

# store all possible seasons
seasons <- unique(dat[["Season"]])
# remove special characters for usage in HTML ids
seasons2 <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", seasons)
names(seasons2) <- seasons

# JavaScript code
js <- "
function(el, x) {
  el.on('plotly_click', function(d) {
    var point = d.points[0];
    var season = point.x;
    Shiny.setInputValue('season', season);
  });
}"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Overall", plotlyOutput("ggly_overall")),
    id = "tabset"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output[["ggly_overall"]] <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(aveWidth, type = "bar",
            x = ~Season, y = ~Average_width
    ) %>% onRender(js)
  })
  
  seasonData <- eventReactive(input[["season"]], {
    filter(aveWidth_filtered, Season == input[["season"]])
  })
  
  # create a renderable plotly graphic for each season
  lapply(
    seasons2, 
    function(season) {
      output[[paste0("ggly_", season)]] <<- renderPlotly({
        data <- seasonData()
        plot_ly(data, type = "scatter", mode = "markers", 
                x = ~ Species, y = ~ Average_width
        )
      })
    }
  )

  existingTabs <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input[["season"]], {
    # if the tab for this season has already been created, then show it
    if(input[["season"]] %in% existingTabs()) {
      showTab("tabset", input[["season"]], select = TRUE)
    } else {
      # record this season
      existingTabs(c(existingTabs(), input[["season"]]))
      # append the new tab
      appendTab(
        "tabset",
        tab = tabPanel(
          title = input[["season"]],
          plotlyOutput(paste0("ggly_", seasons2[input[["season"]]]))
        ),
        select = TRUE
      )
    }
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really helpful.
I'm still facing a slight issue of stacked bars, all the stacked bars in one bar seem to have the same click input. If I choose another colour in the stack, it doesn't open a new tab, ie if I'd already click the big bar before, then nothing will show up since the tab is already open
Basically what I want to do is, whichever specific bar I click, it should open a "Filtered" tab with the data table filtered based on the bar. So if I open it once, and go back to Home and click another bar, then it should remove the previous "Filtered" and replace it

Comment: @yashas107 So you need the "second case". For a stacked bar plot, the label of the clicked piece of bar is in `d.points[0].data.name` in JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you! Another question, I'm having trouble actually removing the tab, I want to remove tabs that start with "Month" in their title, since the content after can differ.

Comment: I tried - observeEvent(input$MPA, { tabset_id <- "tabset" # Get a list of all existing tabs existing_tabs <- names(input[[tabset_id]]) # Find tabs that start with "Month" using grepl tabs_to_remove <- existing_tabs[grepl("^Month", existing_tabs)] v <- sapply(tabs_to_remove, function(x) as.character(x)) w <- c(v) # Remove the found tabs for(tab in setdiff(w, input[["MPA"]])) { removeTab("tabset", tab) } # append the new tab with the modified MPA appendTab( "tabset", tab = tabPanel( title = input[["MPA"]], print("hellolo") ), select = TRUE ) })